# How do I retrieve the name of superuser in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

```
users = User.objects.all()
post.author = users.name
```

Considering that `User` is where superuser's info is stored in the database. It throws an error as:

`'Query Set' object has no attribute 'name'`

Comment: `users` is queryset not an `User` object

Comment: Which superuser do you want to get the name of? The user making a request can be accessed via `request.user` although they may not be a superuser

Answer (score 3):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
superusers = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)
superuser_names = [user.username for user in superusers]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a view that superuser is logged in you can check username by:

```
if request.user.is_superuser:
    name = request.user.username
else:
    name = None
```

Answer (score 0):

`user = User.objects.all()` returns a `queryset` containing all the user in the db, therefore you can't use `.name` on it.

As far as I understood your problem you want the `username` of `user` therefore you should use `user.username` if want first name use `user.first_name`, this will work only on **single object NOT on the queryset**. You can user `user.is_superuser` to find if user is superuser or not.

This will help -> [Read More in Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/)